# Video Sequencer: What are the advantages of Effect Strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Let's say that I want to change the color balance of a strip, I can either:

- Select the strip, open the *N* panel, click on the *Modifiers* tab and create a *Color Balance* modifier
- Or select the strip, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Add Effect Strip > Transform*, keep the effect strip selected and give it a *Color Balance* modifier, which will affect the original strip

What are the advantages of the second solution? I've cited *Color Balance* but I could ask about the transforms as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: me personally i can only "effect strip" -> "add" if i select two strips minimum. Are u using the old Blender versions again!? 

Comment: You can give an effect strip to a single strip, even in 3.1: select a strip, Shift A > Add Effect Strip > Transform, and you can transform the effect strip or give it a modifier, not sure what are the advantages (maybe for the transform operations, you can easily mute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a Transform Effect Strip to color balance a strip, you can just add a `Adjustment Layer` for that. It works just as Adjustment layers in other programs.
Setting its blend mode to `Cross` will then allow you to adjust its "influence" with the opacity value.

So the advantage of using it instead of applying the effect directly to the strip as a modifier is the ability to change this "influence" with the opacity value and the ability to toggle all the effects on and off more easily by just hiding/unhiding the layer.

Another advantage of the Adjustment layer is that you can apply it to more than one strip as it influences all the strips that are underneath it instead of being just limited to one strip like Effects Strips :

[image: The adjustment layer affecting 3 strips at the same time]

It is also good to know that you can apply Effect Strips to an Adjustment Layer which would allow you to apply an effect strip(s) to multiple strips without having to group them into a metastrip.

In conclusion, as an answer to your question, I would suggest you to apply directly the color balance as a modifier if it's just a basic one that you want to apply to single strip but use an Adjustment layer if you want to have more control over it and/or use it on multiple strips.

You should use the Transform strip only if you need to perform transformations (rotate, scale, translate) to your strip.

As a side note, I would like to point out that you can transform a strip without using the Transform Effect Strip, there is a Transform section under the strip tab :

[image]

which allows you to do pretty much the same thing as a transform strip would hence making the transform strip almost pointless.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, so from what I understand, Effect Strip > Transform is rather useless. Maybe something that is missing is a way to control the opacity of an effect strip only.

Comment: Frankly, since the Transform strip crops the image to what's visible, I don't really see a reason to use it instead of the default transform. It can be handy if you want to stack transformations tho and the VSE transform tools addon uses it to stabilize a footage but this crop thing is really annoying.

Comment: One thing I always do if I use an effect strip is, hide the original strip and set the effect strip to alpha over, this way I can control the opacity of the effect strip.